# Bibstyle: capital last names and seperated with semicolon

Tags: biblatex

I need help with changing my bibstyle. I would like my bibstyle to look similar to the `geschichtsfrkl` style but would like to change the separation for multiple authors from "/" to ";".

Does anyone know how to do so? Or maybe a style exists so it looks similar to this:

[image]

respectively for multiple authors:

[image]

I am using `biblatex`.
Another issue is that command `[maxcitenames = 2]` is not working for me, it doesn't shorten multiple authors to et al..
I would be happy if someone could help me out.

Comment: In theory `maxcitenames` should work as advertised. We can only investigate this problem if you can show us a small example document that reproduces how it does not work for you. (We need a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.) Please note that a question on this site should be about one issue only, so please ask a new question about `maxcitenames`, so this question here can be focussed on the name formatting. That way your question is easier to answer for people and more helpful for future visitors of the site.

Answer (score 0):

`geschichtsfrkl` uses the non-standard command `\autorentrennzeichen` to control the punctuation between names, so we could change that

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=geschichtsfrkl]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\autorentrennzeichen}{\addsemicolon\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum\footcite{aksin}
dolor\footcite{worman}
sit\footcite{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma; Ryde, Ulf]

---

However, unless you have to use the exact same format `geschichtsfrkl` that implements, I would recommend going for one of the more standard styles. `geschichtsfrkl` does not always use the common `biblatex` idioms, which means it can be tricky to customise.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamdelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamdelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
dolor \autocite{aksin}
sit \autocite{nussbaum,westfahl:space}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma; Ryde, Ulf (1998). „Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]